# How to put form on same line

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if anyone can help on putting my form on the same line but keeping the button down below. I have tried everything from searching the web to looking on YouTube

```css
    .input select {
 background-color: #000;
 color: #fff;
 width: 100px;
 font-size: 20px;
    }
    form { 
 margin: 0 auto; 
 width:220px;
    }
```

```html
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="#">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input date required">
        <select name="birthday[month]">
                <option value="01" selected="selected">January</option>
                <option value="02">February</option>
                <option value="03">March</option>
                <option value="04">April</option>
                <option value="05">May</option>
                <option value="06">June</option>
                <option value="07">July</option>
                <option value="08">August</option>
                <option value="09">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
            <select name="birthday[day]">
                <option value="01" selected="selected">1</option>
                <option value="02">2</option>
                <option value="03">3</option>
                <option value="04">4</option>
                <option value="05">5</option>
                <option value="06">6</option>
                <option value="07">7</option>
                <option value="08">8</option>
                <option value="09">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="31">31</option>
            </select>
            <select name="birthday[year]">
                <option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                <option value="1989">1989</option>
                <option value="1988">1988</option>
                <option value="1987">1987</option>
                <option value="1986">1986</option>
                <option value="1985">1985</option>
                <option value="1984">1984</option>
                <option value="1983">1983</option>
                <option value="1982">1982</option>
                <option value="1981">1981</option>
                <option value="1980">1980</option>
                <option value="1979">1979</option>
                <option value="1978">1978</option>
                <option value="1977">1977</option>
                <option value="1976">1976</option>
                <option value="1975">1975</option>
                <option value="1974">1974</option>
                <option value="1973">1973</option>
                <option value="1972">1972</option>
                <option value="1971">1971</option>
                <option value="1970">1970</option>
                <option value="1969">1969</option>
                <option value="1968">1968</option>
                <option value="1967">1967</option>
                <option value="1966">1966</option>
                <option value="1965">1965</option>
                <option value="1964">1964</option>
                <option value="1963">1963</option>
                <option value="1962">1962</option>
                <option value="1961">1961</option>
                <option value="1960">1960</option>
                <option value="1959">1959</option>
                <option value="1958">1958</option>
                <option value="1957">1957</option>
                <option value="1956">1956</option>
                <option value="1955">1955</option>
                <option value="1954">1954</option>
                <option value="1953">1953</option>
                <option value="1952">1952</option>
                <option value="1951">1951</option>
                <option value="1950">1950</option>
                <option value="1949">1949</option>
                <option value="1948">1948</option>
                <option value="1947">1947</option>
                <option value="1946">1946</option>
                <option value="1945">1945</option>
                <option value="1944">1944</option>
                <option value="1943">1943</option>
                <option value="1942">1942</option>
                <option value="1941">1941</option>
                <option value="1940">1940</option>
                <option value="1939">1939</option>
                <option value="1938">1938</option>
                <option value="1937">1937</option>
                <option value="1936">1936</option>
                <option value="1935">1935</option>
                <option value="1934">1934</option>
                <option value="1933">1933</option>
                <option value="1932">1932</option>
                <option value="1931">1931</option>
                <option value="1930">1930</option>
                <option value="1929">1929</option>
                <option value="1928">1928</option>
                <option value="1927">1927</option>
                <option value="1926">1926</option>
                <option value="1925">1925</option>
                <option value="1924">1924</option>
                <option value="1923">1923</option>
                <option value="1922">1922</option>
                <option value="1921">1921</option>
                <option value="1920">1920</option>
                <option value="1919">1919</option>
                <option value="1918">1918</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: My Form]

Any help is much appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have each `select` at 100px width. Because you have 3 `select`, so the form width should be > 300px. Just change the width in `form` to `width: 320px;`

```css
.input select {
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
width: 100px;
font-size: 20px;
}
form { 
margin: 0 auto; 
width: 320px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="#">
 <div style="display:none;">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>
 </div>

 <div class="input date required">
  <select name="birthday[month]">
   <option value="01" selected="selected">January</option>
   <option value="02">February</option>
   <option value="03">March</option>
   <option value="04">April</option>
   <option value="05">May</option>
   <option value="06">June</option>
   <option value="07">July</option>
   <option value="08">August</option>
   <option value="09">September</option>
   <option value="10">October</option>
   <option value="11">November</option>
   <option value="12">December</option>
  </select>
  <select name="birthday[day]">
   <option value="01" selected="selected">1</option>
   <option value="02">2</option>
   <option value="03">3</option>
   <option value="04">4</option>
   <option value="05">5</option>
   <option value="06">6</option>
   <option value="07">7</option>
   <option value="08">8</option>
   <option value="09">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
   <option value="11">11</option>
   <option value="12">12</option>
   <option value="13">13</option>
   <option value="14">14</option>
   <option value="15">15</option>
   <option value="16">16</option>
   <option value="17">17</option>
   <option value="18">18</option>
   <option value="19">19</option>
   <option value="20">20</option>
   <option value="21">21</option>
   <option value="22">22</option>
   <option value="23">23</option>
   <option value="24">24</option>
   <option value="25">25</option>
   <option value="26">26</option>
   <option value="27">27</option>
   <option value="28">28</option>
   <option value="29">29</option>
   <option value="30">30</option>
   <option value="31">31</option>
  </select>
  <select name="birthday[year]">
   <option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
   <option value="2017">2017</option>
   <option value="2016">2016</option>
   <option value="2015">2015</option>
   <option value="2014">2014</option>
   <option value="2013">2013</option>
   <option value="2012">2012</option>
   <option value="2011">2011</option>
   <option value="2010">2010</option>
   <option value="2009">2009</option>
   <option value="2008">2008</option>
   <option value="2007">2007</option>
   <option value="2006">2006</option>
   <option value="2005">2005</option>
   <option value="2004">2004</option>
   <option value="2003">2003</option>
   <option value="2002">2002</option>
   <option value="2001">2001</option>
   <option value="2000">2000</option>
   <option value="1999">1999</option>
   <option value="1998">1998</option>
   <option value="1997">1997</option>
   <option value="1996">1996</option>
   <option value="1995">1995</option>
   <option value="1994">1994</option>
   <option value="1993">1993</option>
   <option value="1992">1992</option>
   <option value="1991">1991</option>
   <option value="1990">1990</option>
   <option value="1989">1989</option>
   <option value="1988">1988</option>
   <option value="1987">1987</option>
   <option value="1986">1986</option>
   <option value="1985">1985</option>
   <option value="1984">1984</option>
   <option value="1983">1983</option>
   <option value="1982">1982</option>
   <option value="1981">1981</option>
   <option value="1980">1980</option>
   <option value="1979">1979</option>
   <option value="1978">1978</option>
   <option value="1977">1977</option>
   <option value="1976">1976</option>
   <option value="1975">1975</option>
   <option value="1974">1974</option>
   <option value="1973">1973</option>
   <option value="1972">1972</option>
   <option value="1971">1971</option>
   <option value="1970">1970</option>
   <option value="1969">1969</option>
   <option value="1968">1968</option>
   <option value="1967">1967</option>
   <option value="1966">1966</option>
   <option value="1965">1965</option>
   <option value="1964">1964</option>
   <option value="1963">1963</option>
   <option value="1962">1962</option>
   <option value="1961">1961</option>
   <option value="1960">1960</option>
   <option value="1959">1959</option>
   <option value="1958">1958</option>
   <option value="1957">1957</option>
   <option value="1956">1956</option>
   <option value="1955">1955</option>
   <option value="1954">1954</option>
   <option value="1953">1953</option>
   <option value="1952">1952</option>
   <option value="1951">1951</option>
   <option value="1950">1950</option>
   <option value="1949">1949</option>
   <option value="1948">1948</option>
   <option value="1947">1947</option>
   <option value="1946">1946</option>
   <option value="1945">1945</option>
   <option value="1944">1944</option>
   <option value="1943">1943</option>
   <option value="1942">1942</option>
   <option value="1941">1941</option>
   <option value="1940">1940</option>
   <option value="1939">1939</option>
   <option value="1938">1938</option>
   <option value="1937">1937</option>
   <option value="1936">1936</option>
   <option value="1935">1935</option>
   <option value="1934">1934</option>
   <option value="1933">1933</option>
   <option value="1932">1932</option>
   <option value="1931">1931</option>
   <option value="1930">1930</option>
   <option value="1929">1929</option>
   <option value="1928">1928</option>
   <option value="1927">1927</option>
   <option value="1926">1926</option>
   <option value="1925">1925</option>
   <option value="1924">1924</option>
   <option value="1923">1923</option>
   <option value="1922">1922</option>
   <option value="1921">1921</option>
   <option value="1920">1920</option>
   <option value="1919">1919</option>
   <option value="1918">1918</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <button class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your form needs to be `220px` wide, you can put `display: flex` on your containing `.input` div.

```css
.input select {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 220px;
}

.input {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="#">
  <div style="display:none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST" />
  </div>
  <div class="input date required">
    <select name="birthday[month]">
      <option value="01" selected="selected">January</option>
      <option value="02">February</option>
    </select>
    <select name="birthday[day]">
      <option value="01" selected="selected">1</option>
      <option value="02">2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="birthday[year]">
      <option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```